# How to combine number and pattern formatters in Google Visualization?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a pattern format to display links in a table:

```
 var options = { allowHtml: true,
    cssClassNames: someClass,
    width: 10,
    height: 10
 };

 var patterFormat = '<a href="http://somelink/{0}">{0}</a>';
 var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(patterFormat);
 formatter.format(tableData, [0, 0]); 

 table.draw(tableData, options);
```

`{0}` is just ID (eg 12345).

For some reason recently the result of this code has been changed (may be some updates) and now I am getting on a rendered HTML page ID with a decimal separator, eg `<a href="http://somelink/12,345">12,345</a>` instead of just 12345. The kind of the separator depends on local settings of PC. I know that I can set number format and get rid of the separator but in this way I'll lose the link. Can someone suggest me how can set number format for pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine a Number Format with Pattern Format

just need to use Number Format first

see `User Id` column in following example

*another option* would be to provide the number format directly in the `data`

each cell in a Data Table can have a value (`v:`) and a formatted value (`f:`)

for the `Customer Id` column, the formatted value is provided, so only need to use Pattern Format

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'},
        {label: 'User Id', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Customer Id', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Amount', type: 'number'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: 44836}, {v: 067205, f: '067205'}, {v: 1122}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: 86495}, {v: 067205, f: '067205'}, {v: 332}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: 44836}, {v: 228626, f: '228626'}, {v: 0}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 01, 01')}, {v: 86495}, {v: 228626, f: '228626'}, {v: 334}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: 44836}, {v: 067205, f: '067205'}, {v: 554}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: 86495}, {v: 067205, f: '067205'}, {v: 0}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: 44836}, {v: 228626, f: '228626'}, {v: 0}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date('2016, 02, 01')}, {v: 86495}, {v: 228626, f: '228626'}, {v: 544}]},
      ]
    });

    // format User Id number first
    var numberFormat = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
      pattern: '0'
    });
    numberFormat.format(data, 1);

    // format User Id pattern
    var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(
      '<a href="http://somelink/{1}">{0}</a>'
    );
    formatter.format(data, [0, 1], 1);

    // format Customer Id pattern
    formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat(
      '<a href="http://somelink/{1}">{0}</a>'
    );
    formatter.format(data, [0, 2], 2);

    new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: 'table-div',
      dataTable: data,
      options: {
        allowHtml: true
      },
      view: {'columns': [1, 2, 3]}
    }).draw();
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table-div"></div>
```

Comment: Yep! Thank you very much!